# Looping the inside of a function until goal is met

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, while-loop

I have an array of users called `randomUserArray`. From there I want to retrieve a random user and pass it on. If the chosen user is the same as `clientNickname` I need the function to start over so it wont return a `randomRecipient` that is also the `clientNickname`. Right now my function will return them anyway.

```
function randomRecipientCalc (clientNickname){
  
  var randomRecipient = randomUserArray[Math.floor((Math.random() * randomUserArray.length) + 0)];

  while (randomRecipient == clientNickname) {

  randomRecipient = randomUserArray[Math.floor((Math.random() * randomUserArray.length) + 0)];
 
  }

  return randomRecipient;

}
```

Let's say I have two users in my array (which would be the minimum at any given time)

```
`var randomUserArray = ["user1","user2"]`
```

and "user1" also being the client

```
var clientNickname = "user1"
```

then I use

```
var Recipient = randomRecipientCalc();
```

to get the user the function chose. Is this case it needs to be "user2".
If it isn't, meaning

```
randomRecipient == clientNickname
```

I have console print an error. Which it does right now.

Comment: If(randomRecipient == clientNickname){return randomRecipientCalc(clientNickname);} else { return randomRecipient)

Comment: You could simplify that using a `do`-`while` loop, but it's working? Please post your input that is not working.

Comment: Note that you'll get an infinite loop (or max stack range exceeded, with @user3791775's answer) with a single-element user array.

Comment: Why not just filter the item you don't want out of the array for purposes of the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify the problem by removing the duplicate element. Example:

```
var temporaryRandomUserArray = randomUserArray.filter(function(ele) {
    return !(ele === clientNickname); // keep if ele not equal to clientNickname
});
temporaryRandomUserArray[Math.floor((Math.random() * randomUserArray.length) + 0)];
...
..
```

Something like this is neat and clear. No need of a recursive function call.

Comment: Yes, indeed. 100+ tries and no doubling users. Seems to work! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working for me:

```
 var randomUserArray = ["b","b","b","c","b","b"];

    function randomRecipientCalc (clientNickname){

      var randomRecipient = randomUserArray[Math.floor((Math.random() * randomUserArray.length) + 0)];

      while (randomRecipient == clientNickname) {

        randomRecipient = randomUserArray[Math.floor((Math.random() * randomUserArray.length) + 0)];

          }

          return randomRecipient;

        }

        console.log(randomRecipientCalc("b"));
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood what the function was supposed to do. Thanks anyway!